# Why my PDF is not readable after edited by iText?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

My PDF is not readable after tried to edit the text.
How to make it works ?

my error message : 
Adobe Reader could not open '495049.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)

Basically the objective is to edit PDF doc and replace particular text.

Input already in binary stream (byte[ ])

I worked on C# environment & iText for the PDF editing lib.

Here's my piece of code :

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(doc.FileStream))
{
    PdfDictionary dict = reader.GetPageN(1);
    PdfObject pdfObject = dict.GetDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    if (pdfObject.IsStream())
    {
        PRStream stream = (PRStream)pdfObject;
        byte[] data = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream);
        stream.SetData(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).Replace("[ReplacmentText]", "Hello World")));
    }
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var ignored = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
        reader.Close();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main mistake is that you retrieve the contents of the memory stream before closing the stamper; actually you don't close it at all!

Only when closing the stamper, the final part of the PDF is written. Thus:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var ignored = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
    ignored.Close();
    reader.Close();
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Your other problem (probably not relevant for your current test documents but in general):

```
stream.SetData(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).Replace("[ReplacmentText]", "Hello World")));
```

This assumes very much, especially that the stream content only contains ASCII bytes, that the place holder   "[ReplacementText]" (I assume this is the correct spelling) occurs in one piece and in the immediate content streams, that the font used to draw the place holder and its replacement uses an ASCII'ish encoding, and that this font has glyphs for all characters in "Hello World". Neither of these assumptions are automatically true.

Comment: thanks for the mistype correction.
sorry, so what's the correct way to do it ? To convert the bytes to string ?

Comment: I got the final PDF with no error... but my text was not getting replaced... any suggestion ?

Comment: As mentioned above, your code assumes very much. PDF is not an easily editable format.

Comment: @Gerry Are you trying to edit very specific documents only? In that case, can you provide a sample? As hinted above, generic PDF editing is very complicated.